# Fit a UIView to screen

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

I would like to add portrait orientation to an application. Is there a way to shrink or fit a UIView (created in a xib) to the screen?

I have landscape sized views in the xib files and would now like to set them to the opposite of using Interface Builder stretching (the center block).

[image]

Or is this possible in code?

Answer (score 3):

In code, you can use `self.myView.frame = self.view.bounds;`. To make is stick that way, `self.myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingStretchableWidth | UIViewAutoresizingStretchableHeight;`

Comment: "To make is stick that way, self.myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingStretchableWidth | UIViewAutoresizingStretchableHeight;" Would that shrink it? I would like the opposite of the image.

Comment: @Helium3 This code would make the view have the exact size of the bounds of the screen. Even after autorotation.

Comment: So both calls would? Just the self.myView.frame = self.view.bounds needs to be called in an Orientation delegate method once the rotation  has occurred, the other works dynamically for shrinking or stretching to screen?

Comment: Both in concert, called once, will dynamically make the view the size of the screen. Just the first alone would, without any resizing properties, cause a one-time change. Both in concert even animates the view size changes.

Comment: Since the view is created from the xib, you might as well set the autoresize mask from the interface builder itself. Actually the whole thing can be done from the interface builder.

Comment: @Rakesh - I can only stretch the view using the autoresize mask in IB. As my views are in landscape and I am trying to add portrait orientation support. Can the views be set to shrink in that mask?

Comment: It works both ways. It responds to the parent view's size change. If parent view shrinks, this will also shrink and vice versa. Actually, whatever is provided as code in this solution to set autoresizemask is the same as the 'center block' in the picture.

Comment: This does not work at all for me. I have a number of UIViewControllers all with their own views on screen. There positions are hard coded because I am using animations for visibility. use both of these methods together I do not get the correct results

Answer (score 1):

### If you are adding this view to `self.view` in the XIB then there are two possibilities,

---

1. If you have created full size view in XIB then You have to turn on all auto-resizing masks for fit to screen.
2. If you have not created full size view in nib then you have to make origin of this view to x=0 and y=0. for settings of auto-resizing masks like you have done.

### If you are adding this view to `self.view` using code then you have to set frames manually.

---

Comment: I set the frames in code yes. I dont override UIView, the UIViews are linked to ViewControllers. Where would I reset the view.frame on rotation so that the animation transition is smooth, or should this be custom? Also, with a complex View positioning structure, I guess I need to write some "mapping" method to reset all the frames on rotation right?

Comment: there is too much code to show right now. I am more wanting to understand my next moves if I want to go from a landscape based application for iPhone and iPad (unique UI for each) to portrait mode. The portrait mode is not a simple resizing. I need replacing of views, resizing of views, removal of views/showing of views based on orientation etc.

Comment: I would like help :) I tried using seperate nibs and loading them on rotation, but they didn't load correctly and I had overlapping nib views etc. Not sure if it is just easier to build the portrait nibs and use resizing masks on that, deleting the current landscape nibs I have.

Comment: please provide screen shots to get me into the problem

Answer (score 0):

The solution for Swift 3 :

```
//define view size
self.mTableView.frame = self.view.bounds
//define resizing
self.mTableView.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
```